# Why display:inline-block can prevent margins collapse?

Tags: html, css, margin

Show a margins collapse here.

```css
.ct1{
background: red;
margin:40px;
border:1px solid;width:100%;
}

.ct2{
background: pink;
margin:40px;
border:1px solid;width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctbox">
<div class="ct1">first</div>
<div class="ct2">second</div>
</div>
```

There will be a margins collapse between two divs `ct1` and `ct2`,the distance between them is not 40px+40px = 80px ,instead of 40px.

Now i add a css statement `display:inline-block;` in `ct1` or `ct2`,the distance between them will become  80px,the margins collapse dispear.Why `display:inline-block;` can prevent margins collapse ?

Answer (score 4):

From this rule, [Collapsing Margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)

- Margins between a floated box and any other box do not collapse (not even between a float and its in-flow children).
- Margins of elements that establish new block formatting contexts (such as floats and elements with 'overflow' other than 'visible') do not collapse with their in-flow children.
- Margins of `inline-block` boxes do not collapse (not even with their in-flow children).

...